# How to tag imageview like Facebook instagram. in ios ( mark coordinates on imageview)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tags

I want to tag something on imageview and have to store in Database and when i'll retrive it fom database, i have to show same co ordinates ta on imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `UIImageView` in your storyboard (or in code) and in your `viewController` create the fowling property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
```

Next, in `viewDidLoad` initialize the tapGesture:

```
self.tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];

self.tapGesture.delegate = self;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];
```

Next, create the handler for tap:

```
- (void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.imageView];
    float squareSize = 10;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, YES, 0);

    [self.imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x-squareSize, point.y - squareSize);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x+squareSize, point.y-squareSize);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x+squareSize, point.y+squareSize);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x-squareSize, point.y+squareSize);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x-squareSize, point.y-squareSize);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0,0,0,1);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.imageView setAlpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

This code draws a square over the imageView. Now you can save the `point` in your database and when you need show the image draw the square tag.

I hope this help you.

Comment: How do we make sure that the point saved in our database will work on any display size (iPhone 6 or 6 plus or SE)